# CSS animation - filter:blur() not working together with transform:scale()

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am working on a CSS animation where text expands and becomes blurry, then returns to normal, several times. To begin a new 'phase' the text must become blurred *before* it's scaled up, then keep the filter throughout the scaling and only lose it when it returns to initial size. This is intended as a distortion effect.

Putting filter:blur at keyframes 0% for the first scaling works just fine. However, on Phase 2, it seems it won't set up a blur filter on a percentage prior to the transform:scale. Alone, the blur in the same keyframes as the scaling is too gradual. Am I doing something wrong or is it an inherent limitation? I'd like to keep this effect without creating a different @keyframes for every phase.

```css
@keyframes distortion {
  0% { filter: blur(8px) }
  12% { transform: scaleX(2); filter: blur(8px) }
  12.5% { transform: scaleX(1); filter: blur(8px) }
  12.51% { transform: initial; filter: none }
  50% { transform: initial; filter: none }  /* Pause */
  50.1% { filter: blur(8px) }  /*Phase 2, here's the problem */
  54% { transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(1.1); filter: blur(8px) }
  54.5% { transform: initial; filter: blur(8px) }
  100% { transform: initial }
}
```

Comment: don't use none or initial .. use blur(0px) and scaleX(1)

Comment: @TemaniAiff Just tried that, it still won't set the blur before the transform starts.